# How to configure NLog (Servicestack) for Multiple files

Tags: c#, servicestack, nlog

I need to save one log file for each of my threads running.

So I want different log files, the code below saves one log, but I need to create diferent ones, how can I call the method saying which file I want to save?

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new NLogFactory();
var log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
log.Info("********************* TASK REPLICATOR STARTED *********************");
```

So I need to configure something like:

```
  <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throwExceptions="true">
    <targets>
      <target name="logging" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${level}.log" archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/${level}.{###}.log" archiveAboveSize="1048576" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="20" concurrentWrites="true" layout="${longdate}|${callsite}|${level}|${message}" />
      <target name="exception" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/${level}.log" archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/${level}.{###}.log" archiveAboveSize="1048576" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="20" concurrentWrites="true" layout="${longdate}|${message}|${exception:format=tostring}" />
      <!-- THIS LINE BELOW DOES WHAT I NEED? -->
      <target name="mynewlogfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/logs/mynewlogfile.log" archiveFileName="${basedir}/logs/archives/TransactionTypes.{###}.log" archiveAboveSize="1048576" archiveNumbering="Sequence" maxArchiveFiles="20" concurrentWrites="true" layout="${longdate}|${callsite}|mynewlogfile|${message}" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" maxlevel="Warn" writeTo="logging" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" maxlevel="Fatal" writeTo="exception" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to simply use `${threadid}` (or if you name your threads, `${threadname}`) in the filename layout.

This will automatically separate log entries into one file for each thread.

```
<target name="mynewlogfile" xsi:type="File" 
        fileName="${basedir}/logs/mynewlogfile-thread-${threadid}.log" 
        ...
        layout="${longdate}|${callsite}|mynewlogfile|${message}" />
```

Comment: Unbelieavable your are a legend! Where can I find documentation for it?

Comment: No problem! [This](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/File-target) is the page for File targets, which tells you that `fileName` is a Layout. And [this](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Layout-Renderers) is the list of "layout renderers" (`${something}` tokens) that you can use in a layout.